# Add SQL SELECT COUNT result to an existing column as text

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I have two tables:

```
1. TABLE [dbo].[ItemCategories](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId] [int] NULL,
    [StockId] [int] NULL,

2. TABLE [dbo].[Categories](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentCategoryId] [int] NULL,
    [CategoryName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Slug] [nvarchar](150) NULL
```

And this query in SQL Server 2012

```
SELECT [CategoryName], [Slug], [ParentCategoryId], [Id] 
FROM [Categories] 
ORDER BY [ParentCategoryId] DESC
```

Which returns these rows

```
[CategoryName]  [Slug]  [ParentCategoryId]  [Id]
Exercise        exercise    42               46
Fashion         fashion     42               47
```

And I have a second query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [ItemCategories]
WHERE CategoryId = '46' <--- This Id is the same as [Id] from the first query
```

How can I a modify the first query to add total count from the second query to the returned `CategoryName` column (as a single string) ?

Like this:

```
 [CategoryName]     [Slug]   [ParentCategoryId] [Id]
Exercise (31)       exercise    42               46
Fashion (56)        fashion     42               47
```

I have created this join, but I don't know how to add the COUNT(*) as text

```
SELECT [CategoryName], [Slug], [ParentCategoryId], [Categories].[Id] 
FROM [Categories] 
INNER JOIN [ItemCategories] ON [Categories].[Id]=[ItemCategories].[CategoryId] 
ORDER BY [ParentCategoryId] DESC
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: BTW, are `[ItemCategories]` and `[Categories]` different tables?

Comment: This is why it's a **really good thing** to show us the definition of the _tables_ in addition to showing us the queries you've tried. You might even want to show us to test data.

Comment: I have added the join query which shows clearly the table reference. and seems that Gordon have understood.

Comment: I have added the table definitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `count(*)` window function.  I would put it in a separate column, but you can do:

```
SELECT [CategoryName] + ' (' + cast(count(*) over (partition by Id) as varchar(255)) + ')',
       [Slug], [ParentCategoryId], [Id] 
FROM [Categories] 
ORDER BY [ParentCategoryId] DESC;
```

EDIT:

For two tables, use a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT c.CategoryName + ' (' + cast(count(ic.Id) as varchar(255)) + ')',
      c.Slug, c.ParentCategoryId, c.Id
FROM Categories c LEFT JOIN
     ItemCategories ic
     on ic.CategoryId = c.Id
GROUP BY c.CategoryName, c.slug, c.ParentCategoryId, c.id
ORDER BY ParentCategoryId DESC;
```

Comment: Except that he now tells us he really meant two tables.

Comment: Thanks! seems to be close to what I want but all the returned counts are (1)

Comment: @MarioM: if you had shown us the definitions of the tables, you would probably have a correct answer by now. I bet that `CategoryName` is functionally dependent on `Id`.

Comment: I have added the table definitions

Comment: Thanks! You have two small spell errors (c.CateoryName and c.ParentCateogryId), but it works now!